# Equivalent of DataOutputStream.readBoolean and DataOutputStream.writeBoolean for ByteBuffer?

Tags: java, networking, bytebuffer

How can I do something like *ByteBuffer.putBoolean* and *ByteBuffer.getBoolean*?

As with *DataInputStream* there is *readBoolean* and with *DataOutputStream* there is *writeBoolean*; I don't find the ability to write/read booleans with ByteBuffer. Is there a way to achieve the same behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

```
    boolean b = buf.get() == 1;
    buf.put((byte) (b ? 1 : 0));
```

Answer (score 3):

See the Javadoc. writeBoolean() writes one byte which is 1 or 0 according as the argument is true or false. So do that.